# PHP Mongo Regular expression

Tags: php, regex, mongodb

I have mongo record as follows.

```
[1] => Array
    (
        [_id] => MongoId Object
            (
            )

        [id] => 195197
        [rec] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 195197
                        [data] => ways to skin a cat
                        [total] => 313
                    )

                 [1] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 702724
                        [data] => 2010-07-25 15:09:40
                    )
            )

          [rec2] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 195197
                        [data] => ways to skin a cat
                        [total] => 313
                    )

                 [1] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 702724
                        [data] => 2010-07-25 15:09:40
                    )
            )
    );
```

I want to search those records from mongo db having rec & rec2 element and having "data" element is in date format through Mongo regular expression. Is any way to find such records?

Answer (score 5):

From the shell you should be able to do something like the following:

```
db.foo.find( { 'rec.data' : /\d\d\d\d-\d\d-\d\d/ } )
```

From PHP, you would use the [MongoRegex class](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.mongoregex.php).

Looks something like this:

```
$regex = new MongoRegex("/\d\d\d\d-\d\d-\d\d/");
$where = array("rec.data" => $regex);
$cursor = $db->foo->find( $where );
```

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively regular expressions can be expressed like so:

```
$where = array("rec.data"=>array('$regex'=>"\d\d\d\d-\d\d-\d\d", '$options'=>""));
$cursor = $db->foo->find( $where );
```

(i'm not sure if options can be omitted if it is blank so i've left it in)